# character string buffer too small error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a table with a select statement. I want to populate this new table with the aggregated value from a VIEW. Following is the code used for creating the VIEW,

```
  create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
 as
 select SESSION_ID, 
        SESSION_DT, 
        C_IP, 
        CS_USER_AGENT,
        tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab)) WEBLINKS
 from web_views_tab    
 group by C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT;
```

I want to create a table with WEBLINKS and SESSION_ID which is a sequence from another table.And when I try to create a table from VIEW (the one without the SESSION_ID), I get the following error,

SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

This has to do with the field, Weblinks, it does have longer values. What can I do now to get around this error??

More information on the aggregate function can be found in [AskTom](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#collect)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column that isn't a part of `GROUP BY` clause or isn't covered by aggregate function. Because it's not possible to know which value should be returned in that case.

If it's guaranteed it's unique per group - you may fool the database with

```
MIN(SESSION_ID) SESSION_ID
```

but keep in mind that's not a good practice to do so :-)

Comment: I see. Then I guess the better alternative would be to first create a view with the selected fields and then create a table with WEBLINKS and a sequence. But like I mentioned before I get the error that the "character string buffer is too small". Any way to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't select fields that's not in group by function. You group few fields with different session_id. How do you think you can select one?

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple select statements here?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not valid now, either you get the columns: `C_IP`, `CS_USER_AGENT` into the group by part like:

```
create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
 as
 select SESSION_ID, 
        SESSION_DT, 
        C_IP, 
        CS_USER_AGENT,
        tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab)) WEBLINKS
 from web_views_tab    
 group by C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT, C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, WEBLINKS;
```

or you change these to use functions which return one value from a set something like COUNT(), AVG(), MAX(), MIN() etc like:

```
create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
 as
 select SESSION_ID, 
        SESSION_DT, 
        COUNT(C_IP), 
        COUNT(CS_USER_AGENT),
        Count(tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab))) WEBLINKS
 from web_views_tab    
 group by C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT;
```

Comment: Thanks, but both of your suggestions give the same error, "not a GROUP BY expression".

Answer (score 1):

Put `session_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause too. You should always put all the non-aggregate function columns in `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I did just experiment with what you've said to see what will turn up.. There are no errors but it doesn't aggregate the records. There are a total of 8190 records. Usually it aggregated to about 1539 records if you don't include the SESSION_ID.

Answer (score 1):

use a CLOB then if the result is > 4000 bytes.

```
SQL> create table web_views_tab(SESSION_ID number, SESSION_DT date, C_IP varchar2(20), CS_USER_AGENT varchar2(10), web_link varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into web_views_tab
  2  select rownum, trunc(sysdate), '127.0.0.1', 'Mozilla', 'http://foo.bar.com/asdakjdlkajdlkajsd/asdjaldjklja'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 3000;

3000 rows created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string (p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
  2                                            p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  3    l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
  4  BEGIN
  5    FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
  6      IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
  7        l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
  8      END IF;
  9      l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
 10    END LOOP;
 11    RETURN l_string;
 12  END tab_to_string;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
  2   as
  3   select SESSION_DT,
  4          C_IP,
  5          CS_USER_AGENT,
  6          tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab)) WEBLINKS
  7   from web_views_tab
  8   group by C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT;

View created.

SQL> select * from FINAL_WEB_LOG;
select * from FINAL_WEB_LOG
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "TEST.TAB_TO_STRING", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

so we redefine the function output as clob and alter the function a bit:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string (p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
  2                                            p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN clob IS
  3    l_string     clob;
  4  BEGIN
  5    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_string, true, dbms_lob.call);
  6     dbms_lob.open(l_string, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  7    FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
  8      IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
  9        dbms_lob.writeappend(l_string, length(p_delimiter), p_delimiter);
 10      END IF;
 11        dbms_lob.writeappend(l_string, length(p_varchar2_tab(i)), p_varchar2_tab(i));
 12    END LOOP;
 13     dbms_lob.close(l_string);
 14    RETURN l_string;
 15  END tab_to_string;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from FINAL_WEB_LOG;

SESSION_D C_IP                 CS_USER_AG
--------- -------------------- ----------
WEBLINKS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-DEC-12 127.0.0.1            Mozilla
http://foo.bar.com/asdakjdlkajdlkajsd/asdjaldjklja,http://foo.bar.com/asdakjdlka
```

Comment: I've tried previously with CLOB data type. When I try to use this column with CLOB data type in the data mining process, it doesn't accept. But it accepts varchar2 data type, hence the problem.